# Exchange 2010 Minimal Hybrid in place : Migrate or Decom?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, microsoft-office-365, exchange-migration, exchange-hybrid

I'm trying to understand the best approach with an Exchange 2010 Server with a ***minimal*** hybrid configuration.

All is migrated to the cloud, the current Exchange 2010 is not in prod, but some mailboxe still need to be adjusted from the Exchange 2010 (like the Enable Archive Mailboxe attribute).

Should I just migrate to 2010, deploy a new Exchange 2016 VM reinstall the minimal hybrid setup, rerun the AADsync to set the schema back in place.

Or just uninstall the Exchange 2010, but I might have issue managing some attribute of the mailboxes because of the sync in place ?

If I need to migrate any advice or pitfall to avoid ? Again it's a Minimal Hybrid not a Full one with the free busy and all those advanced link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now your environment is exchange 2010 minimal hybrid?

We could know the pre-requisites for minimal hybrid:

Use minimal hybrid to migrate emails if you:

-Are running at least one Exchange 2010, Exchange 2013, and/or Exchange 2016 server on-premises.

-Plan to move to Exchange Online over a course of few weeks or less.

-Do not plan to continue to run directory synchronization to manage
your users.

Since exchange 2010 is supported for minimal hybrid, you could remove it after the whole migration.
And you also could use cutover migration which is also no need to run directory synchronization.

Comment: Yes, but if we want to keep the directory synchronization, can I just deploy a minimum Exchange 2016 and minimal hybrid to keep the ADSync up ?

Comment: Yes, of course. You could enable the AD Sync after minimal hybrid again. If the reply is helpful, please mark the helpful replies as answers.